# Flutter : Display Local Image when Network Image not found or error fetching it?

Tags: image, flutter, caching, networking, dart

```
Center(
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: "http:/ sosme link here",
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  fadeInCurve: Curves.easeIn ,
                  fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds:1000),
                  fadeOutCurve: Curves.easeOut,
                  fadeOutDuration: Duration(milliseconds:500),
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    height: 250.0,
                    width: 250.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                    image: imageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

My goal is to load image from URL that may and may not exist.
In case of not existing URL, load asset image.
Tried insert asset image here, but didnt't work. 
As I was thinking if there's error loading it, means no image found or something else. So I wanna display a local image instead.

Any Suggestion?

```
errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
```

Error, when i use asset image

[image: Error, when i use asset image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FadeInImage` widget for your use case..

Here's a sample for you..

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Fade in images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
            image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can get [more information from official website](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images).

Comment: What need to do when we have a URL but got the below exception? ```======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: NetworkImage is an empty file:```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure image exist in the asset folder in the path.
*for Eg:*

```
errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/images/image.jpg'),
```

And declare that path inside `pubspec.yaml` file.
*Eg:*

```
assets:
    - assets/images/image.png
```

Comment: Hello. I tried that. But assuming the URL is not available, it gave me an error(I edited the question by uploading a screenshot).

Comment: @nelsonwong: in your code, I can't see Exception handling, even if you put the wrong URL my code should work as per CachedNetworkImage

Comment: Thanks to @srikanth7785

Solved by using Try/Catch block.

Answer (score -1):

```
CachedNetworkImage(
imageUrl: "your image url",
fit: BoxFit.cover,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
placeholder: (context,url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
errorWidget: (context,url,error) => new Icon(Icons.error))
```

Comment: An explanation would improve this answer